# Azure AD logout issue in multiple browser tabs

Tags: azure-active-directory

I have followed Microsoft website sample to setup a web authentication via Azure AD. I have tested the login via Azure AD, and it was able to logged in and out system. But, I noticed there was an issue when logging out from system. When I duplicate for multiple tabs in browser(chrome, firefox), and logout from one of the duplicated tabs. But other duplicated tabs, still remain logged in status even I refresh them. But when I open a new tab to access again, it required me to login. Below is my code for logout, does anyone know what I have missed out?

```
    protected async Task OnLogout()
{
    if (await DialogService.Confirm("Are you sure want to logout?", "Logout Confirmation",
             new ConfirmOptions() { OkButtonText = "Yes", CancelButtonText = "No" }) == true)
    {
        await SignOutManager.SetSignOutState();
        Navigation.NavigateTo("authentication/logout");
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please share the sample URL?